# Duda sobre recursividad

Tags: c++, quicksort

Tengo entendido que el siguiente problema se refiere a la solución de ordenamiento de datos mediante un Quicksort o al menos eso supone ser, y me han pedido encontrar el error por el cual el programa se atasca, pero por más que he buscado no la encuentro, supuestamente el error se encuentra en el void QT

/*Actualizo*/

Realicé el depurador, con las modificaciones que menciono enseguida y el resultado que me da no es el esperado, no se si sea error de codigo o si realmente no encuentro como reparar el error...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int d(int A[], int b, int z)//Arreglo, izquierda, derecha
{
    int l,r,p,t;
    p=A[b];//Pivote igual a posición  del arreglo
    l=b;//l igual a izquierda (0)
    r=z;//r igual a la derecha (9)
    while (l<r)//Mientras izquierda (0) sea menor a (9)
    {
        while(A[r]>p)//Mientras posición r del arreglo (9) sea mayor a 0
            r--;
        while (l<r && A[l]<=p)
            l++;

        if(l<r)//Si izquierda menor que derecba
        {
            t=A[r];//T igual a arreglo posición r
            A[l]=A[r];//Arreglo posición izquierda igual a arreglo derecha
            A[r]=t;//Arreglo drecha igual a t
        }
    }
    t=A[r];
    A[r]=A[b];
    A[b]=t;
    return r;
}

void QT(int A[],int b,int z)//b izquierda y z derecha
{
    int p;
    if (b<z||b>=z)//-----Cambio
        p=d(A,b,z);
    if (b<z)//--Agregué esta condicion para poder dar fin a la función QT 
        QT(A,b,p-1);
    if (b>z)//--Agregué para dar salida a la siguiente QT
        QT(A,p+1,z);//----No se implementa
}

int main()
{
    int Arr[3]={2,3,1};
    int i;
    printf("ANTES DE QS:");
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)//----Cambio
    printf("%i,",Arr[i]);
    printf("\n \n");

    QT (Arr,0,2);//-----Cambio
    printf("DESPUES DE QS:");
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)//-----Cambio
        printf("%i,",Arr[i]);//Imprime 1,1,2 ni idea por que

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Similar comentario del sitio en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49226087/recursion-quicksort-c), debes esforzarte y usar un depurador, analiza si las variables tomas los valores que esperas, ademas debes mejorar tu pregunta, por ejemplo si tienes un mensaje de error debes añadirlo, en SOes son más permisivos, pero en el ingles son muchos más severos con este tipo de preguntas ya que son muy comunes y los usuarios no se esfuerzan en resolver su problema.

Comment: El error si esta en la función QT, y creo que es muy obvio... opino lo mismo que el comentario de @eyllanesc, asi que como te dijo el, depura el programa, sigue la lógica que implementaste, mira los condicionales que utilizas, mira si cuando entra a al método QT tiene alguna manera de salir de ese método , etc.

Comment: @Mario la única duda que me queda es el por qué llama dos veces la función QT, no entiendo como procede el programa en esa situación:

Comment: @progracrack y de hecho no es la única pregunta que debes hacerte, la otra pregunta es, cuando se supone que el flujo del programa sale del método QT?

Comment: @prografail Analiza el algoritmo, probablemente estás accediendo a memoria que no debes... que el programa compile, no significa que no haya errores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El algoritmo QuickSort, es un algoritmo de ordenamiento rápido, este funciona en 3 fases:

1. Se selecciona un elemento que va hacer el pivote, idealmente debe ser el valor central de la lista, este algoritmo tiene un mejor desempeño cuando el pivote que se elige es el del centro.
2. Se reorganiza la lista de tal manera que los elementos inferiores al pivote queden a la izquierda y los mayores queden a la derecha.
3. Se separan la lista en dos sublistas, una es la parte izquierda del pivote y la otra la derecha, y se repite el todo el proceso(recursividad) a estas dos sublistas.

[image: Sorting quicksort anim.gif]
De en:User:RolandH, [CC BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), [Enlace](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=1965827),
[Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

Realice muchísimas correcciones al código, empezando  por las cabeceras, porque incluías a la librería `string.h` si no hacías uso de esta, una de las cosas que hay que tener presente, es la ubicación del pivote, este es fundamental para el rendimiento del algoritmo, existen varios métodos para mejorar esto el cual no utilizo ninguno, solo lo ubico en el centro de la lista, buscando un poco de "suerte" para que sea un dato conveniente por así decirlo.

Puedes encontrarte este código en muchos lugares donde busques quickSort, cambia la lógica en como lo aplica cada programador, pero el algoritmo siempre tiende hacer el mismo.

Solo utilizo una función en lugar de dos porque así me siento mas cómodo, ahora una de las dudas que tenias era el por qué llamaba a la función dos veces, bueno la lista es separada en dos sublistas, una con los valores inferiores al pivote, y la otra con los valores superiores, esos dos condicionales lo que hacen comprobar que se termine de ordenar una sublista, para entrar a ordenar la otra.

Ten en cuenta que al ser recursivo, esta se llamara las veces que sea necesaria, de pende mucho del tamaño que tenga la lista, una lista muy grande sera separada en dos sublistas, que estas a su vez pueden ser separadas en mas sublistas y así recursivamente hasta ordenar la lista entera.

```
#include <iostream>

#define N_ARRAY 5

void quick_sort(int arr[],int inicio,int fin);

int main()
{
    int arr[N_ARRAY]={2,3,1,5,4};

    std::cout << "ANTES DE QS:" << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < N_ARRAY; i++)//----Cambio
        std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;

    std::cout << "\n\n";

    quick_sort(arr, 0, N_ARRAY);
    std::cout << "DESPUES DE QS:" << std::endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < N_ARRAY; i++)
        std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

void quick_sort(int arr[],int inicio,int fin)
{   
    int inicioAux = inicio, finAux = fin;
    int pivote = arr[static_cast<int>((inicio + fin) / 2)];

    while( inicioAux < finAux)
    {
        while(arr[inicioAux] < pivote)
            ++inicioAux;
        while(arr[finAux] > pivote)
            --finAux;

        if( inicioAux <= finAux)
        {
            int temp = arr[inicioAux];
            arr[inicioAux] = arr[finAux];
            arr[finAux] = temp; 
            ++inicioAux;
            --finAux;
        }
    }

    if( inicio < finAux)
        quick_sort(arr, inicio, finAux);
    if(inicioAux < fin)
        quick_sort(arr, inicioAux, fin);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario, respectoa  tu respuesta considero fue la más completa y ahora me ayuda a comprender mejor el tema, última solicitud de información que realizo... ¿El programa que me proporcionaron era funcional entonces o no? Y de ser la respuesta si, ¿Cual era la correción que debía hacer en la función QT para hacerlo funcionar? No es que no me esfuerce, pero entiendo que era la imposible salida de la llamada recursiva, por lo tanto agregué las condicionales que señalo en el codigo pero imprime la lista de otra manera.